# Apache 2.4 rewrite rule not working

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm using Apache HTTP Server v2.4.

I want to make a rewrite rule: *If the file is not found to return `/index.html`*

I'm using this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

but I get 400 Bad Request for every request (even the root one, or the /index.html one).

NOTE:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^/(.*) - [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [QSA,L]
```

does work properly.

Anyone has the idea, what is going on?

Comment: There are some special considerations for the REQUEST_FILENAME in the [manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) so depending on when and where you place your rules (.htaccess , the main httpd.conf, in a VirtualHost or Directory section) and/or other directives in play it might not make the expected mapping.

Comment: I put both of the snippets in `httpd.conf`, but the first code excerpt is suggested for `.htaccess`. You think this can be the cause?

Comment: Since directives placed in .htaccess files can only be applied after the request has been mapped to the local file system (necessary for apache httpd to be able to find the .htaccess file in the first place) using the REQUEST_FILENAME in .htaccess is much more safe than using it in httpd.conf